# Why does my Spring 3.2 mixed configuration results in an exception?

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration, annotations

I have Spring 3.2 code here for which I changed the xml configuration (most of it) to java configuration. Also there are some @Component annotations for some beans.

Within the web.xml it starts with:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
  <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
  <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>com.tms.core.configuration</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

Then we have the following java configuration (com.tms.configurations):

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan("com.tms.core")
@ImportResource({"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
@EnableTransactionManagement(order = 35)
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:applicationContext.properties"})
public class TMSApplicationConfig
 {
  @Autowired(required = true)
  private ApplicationContext ctx;


  @Bean
  public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager()
   {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(this.ctx.getBean("entityManagerFactory", LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.class).getNativeEntityManagerFactory());
   }

  /*
  @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
  public BasicDataSource dataSource()
   {
    final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(this.ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(this.ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(this.ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(this.ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty("jdbc.password"));
    dataSource.setMaxTotal(Integer.parseInt(this.ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty("jdbc.maxConnections")));
    dataSource.setPoolPreparedStatements(false);
    return dataSource;
   }
  */

  // [...]
 }
```

Also then we have the applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd" default-autowire="byType">

  <mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />

  <bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer" p:fileEncoding="UTF-8" p:location="classpath:applicationContext.properties">
    <property name="propertiesPersister">
      <bean class="com.tms.core.common.EncryptedPropertiesReader" />
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" p:basenames="classpath:/tms-messages,classpath:/tms-labels" p:cacheSeconds="1" p:useCodeAsDefaultMessage="true" p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.url}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" p:maxTotal="${jdbc.maxConnections}" p:poolPreparedStatements="false" />

  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
      <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" p:database="${jdbc.database}" p:showSql="false" p:generateDdl="${jdbc.generateDdl}" />
    </property>
  </bean>

  <!-- ... -->
</beans>
```

Last but not least a component beans:

```
@Component
public class ServiceExecutionContext
 {
  @Autowired
  public ServiceExecutionContext(final DataSource dataSource, final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, final IUserManager userManager, final IDocumentManager documentManager)
   {
    super();
     // [...]
   }
 }
```

The problem now is that I get the following exception:

```
$Â° WARNÂ° 2019-09-26T11:13:40,825Â° mainÂ° Â° org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContextÂ° Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name &apos;serviceExecutionContext&apos; defined in file [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\com\tms\core\service\ServiceExecutionContext.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]: : Error creating bean with name &apos;transactionManager&apos; defined in class path resource [com&#x2F;tms&#x2F;core&#x2F;configuration&#x2F;TMSApplicationConfig.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean &apos;TMSApplicationConfig&apos;; factory method &apos;transactionManager()&apos;. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name &apos;transactionManager&apos; defined in class path resource [com&#x2F;tms&#x2F;core&#x2F;configuration&#x2F;TMSApplicationConfig.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean &apos;TMSApplicationConfig&apos;; factory method &apos;transactionManager()&apos;. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.
$Â° ERRORÂ° 2019-09-26T11:13:40,841Â° mainÂ° Â° org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderÂ° Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceExecutionContext' defined in file [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\com\tms\core\service\ServiceExecutionContext.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]: : Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [com/tms/core/configuration/TMSApplicationConfig.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'TMSApplicationConfig'; factory method 'transactionManager()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [com/tms/core/configuration/TMSApplicationConfig.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'TMSApplicationConfig'; factory method 'transactionManager()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:752)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1077)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:981)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:638)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4663)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5131)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1133)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1868)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
  at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1045)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:429)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1577)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:934)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
  at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:933)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:637)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [com/tms/core/configuration/TMSApplicationConfig.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'TMSApplicationConfig'; factory method 'transactionManager()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:550)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1057)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:923)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:866)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:781)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:745)
  ... 56 more
```

As you can see the transactionManager() method is there within TMSApplicationConfig and it is also not static.

I have already tried to understand the source at [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3.2.x/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/ConstructorResolver.java) to find out more about the problem, but without luck.

What I am not really understand is for the `dataSource` example - that when enabling it within the java config (and disable it within xml) it will result in the same exception - and when moving it back to xml then it works.

So it looks to me a bit like xml and component annotated classes have no access to the java configuration - but why? I thought it will be all within one configuration held internally?

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE 1:**

I have now fixed the ApplicationContext handling (as mentioned by @M. Deinum), but the Exception is still the same.

**UPDATE 2:**

Added complete stack trace.
Removed XML tx management.
Debugged spring 3.2.18 `ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod()`

[image]

The `beanName` here is correct, also the `factoryBeanName` is correct.
But what leads to the error is that the `factoryBean` itself is a proxy - and this proxy has no method names from `TMSApplicationConfig` so the beanName method 'transactionManager' could not be found.

Added important part of maven dependencies (exclusions removed):

```
  <properties>
    <springVersion>3.2.18.RELEASE</springVersion>
    <springSecurityVersion>3.2.10.RELEASE</springSecurityVersion>
  </properties>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
      <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>${springSecurityVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
      <version>${springSecurityVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.2.Final</version> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1-b06</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1-b11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.21.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.21.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**UPDATE 3**

Excluded configration from component scan.
Also made configuration return types more explicit.
Removed exclusions from dependencies (only here, because the question was to large).

From debugging some more information:

The generated Proxy class is: `com.tms.configuration.TMSApplicationConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe47f862@498ae73c`

The methods found by `ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod()` are as follows:

```
Proxy.newProxyInstance(java.lang.ClassLoader,java.lang.Class[],java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler)
Proxy.isProxyClass(java.lang.Class),
Proxy.getProxyClass0(java.lang.ClassLoader,java.lang.Class[]),
Proxy.getProxyClass(java.lang.ClassLoader,java.lang.Class[])
Proxy.getInvocationHandler(java.lang.Object)
Proxy.defineClass0(java.lang.ClassLoader,java.lang.String,byte[],int,int),
Proxy.checkProxyAccess(java.lang.Class,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.lang.Class[]),
Proxy.checkNewProxyPermission(java.lang.Class,java.lang.Class),
Proxy.access$300(java.lang.ClassLoader,java.lang.String,byte[],int,int),
Proxy.access$200(),
Object.wait(long,int) throws java.lang.InterruptedException,
Object.wait(long
Object.wait() throws java.lang.InterruptedException,
Object.toString(),
Object.registerNatives()´
Object.notifyAll(),
Object.notify(),
Object.hashCode(),
Object.getClass(),
Object.finalize() throws java.lang.Throwable,
Object.equals(java.lang.Object),
Object.clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException,
$Proxy76.toString(), 
$Proxy76.toProxyConfigString(),
$Proxy76.setTargetSource(org.springframework.aop.TargetSource),
$Proxy76.setPreFiltered(boolean),
$Proxy76.setExposeProxy(boolean),
$Proxy76.replaceAdvisor(org.springframework.aop.Advisor,org.springframework.aop.Advisor)
$Proxy76.removeAdvisor(org.springframework.aop.Advisor),
$Proxy76.removeAdvisor(int) 
$Proxy76.removeAdvice(org.aopalliance.aop.Advice),
$Proxy76.isProxyTargetClass(),
$Proxy76.isPreFiltered(),
$Proxy76.isInterfaceProxied(java.lang.Class),
$Proxy76.isFrozen(),
$Proxy76.isExposeProxy(),
$Proxy76.indexOf(org.springframework.aop.Advisor),
$Proxy76.indexOf(org.aopalliance.aop.Advice),
$Proxy76.hashCode(), 
$Proxy76.getTargetSource(),
$Proxy76.getTargetClass(),
$Proxy76.getProxiedInterfaces(),
$Proxy76.getAdvisors(),
$Proxy76.equals(java.lang.Object), 
$Proxy76.destroy() throws java.lang.Exception,
$Proxy76.addAdvisor(org.springframework.aop.Advisor)
$Proxy76.addAdvisor(int,org.springframework.aop.Advisor)
$Proxy76.addAdvice(org.aopalliance.aop.Advice)
$Proxy76.addAdvice(int,org.aopalliance.aop.Advice)
```

So as I said within the proxy there are no methods from the original TMSApplicationConfiguration class - which leads to the exception and the question why the methods are not found within the proxy?

Comment: What a contraption. Remove the loading of the context from the method, that is part of the problem. Just add `EntityManagerFactory` as a method argument to `transactionManager`.

Comment: I changed that as you suggested, but when the autowire of the component constructor searches for the transactionManager it will not (also) autowire the entityManagerFactory - because it only searches for transactionManager() instead of transactionmanager(EntityManagerFactory) ...

Comment: No it won't, unless you are referencing that somewhere in your code. The problem with your current code is that in your configuration you are loading a context, which gets disposed but use beans from it. That is wrong, next to that the context being loaded, will load another context, which will load another context, which will load another context etc. etc. etc. Another issue lies in the fact of duplicating things in XML and java. `<tx:annotation-driven />` - `@EnableTransactionManagement`, use one of them. `@PropertySource` and your `placeholderConfig` are partially duplicates.

Comment: Yes I know. Thats because that is old Spring 2.0 code that I am trying to refactor and it looks like the step from Spring 2.5 to 3.x is the hardest part.

Comment: If you are only upgrading Spring then why move to java config? XML is still valid. Just update the dependencies and stick with XML. Moving to a newer version doesn't require using java config. Heck the XML is still valid with Spring 5.2.

Comment: Yes I know, but there are configuration errors within the xml code I could find simpler with the java config ;-)

Comment: Apparently not, as it isn't working. XML should be fine and still be compatible (unless you use some deprecated namespace features).

Comment: I have fixed the context handling by using an autowired ApplicationContext now.

Comment: Are you by any chance using conflicting jars from different spring versions? And as mentioned before you really shouldn't be using the context but rather inject the `EntityManagerFactory` into the method as an argument. You should also not have duplicate tx management block (either remove the annotation or the xml element). having multiple and injecting the context can lead to eager init issues, leading to non proxied config classes. Finally please add your dependencies to your question.

Comment: My dependencies are clean, because I am using Maven Enforcer Plugin 8-) Also removed the xml tx management block - I also have removed all the multiple context. Dependencies will follow later - at the moment I am trying to debug the initialization.

Comment: The fact that you use the enforcer plugin doesn't have to mean your dependencies are clean... So again please add your dependencies and as well please add the full stacktrace instead of a snippet.

Comment: So with update 2 I added all things you asked for, also I added what I found by debugging - looks like a wrong proxy is used for the Configuration class.

Comment: Ofcourse the factory is a proxy as that is how `@Configuration` files are processed. So yes it will be a proxy. Looking at your configuraiton do you really need `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` ? Do you have additional aspects that need to be processed. Also try to exclude `@Configuration` class from the `@ComponentScan` (older versions has some issues with duplicate registrations). If you have a `<context:component-scan />` left in your xml execlude `@Configuration` classes from it. Be explicit in your return types from `@Bean` methods, so `JpaTransactionManager` over `PlatformTransactionManager`.

Comment: Added Update 3 - more information about the proxy from debugging. Yes I have aspects. I have moved the Configuration to an own package outside the component scan. No `<context:component-scan />`. Made all return types in configuration explicit. Still the same exception ...

Comment: Try without the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` as that seems to be an issue, looks like you have a proxy of a proxy.

Comment: Ok, I disabled `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`, but that seems to change nothing. I have also diabled the `<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />` but that also changed nothing.

Comment: Looks like I have no other choice than moving back to xml configuration.

Comment: The `<mvc:annotation-driven />` won't change a thing as that is only for enabling the request handling for annotation based controllers. There must be something in your configuration that triggers the double proxy or general garbling of your configuration classes. There should be no problem in using java config with Spring 3.2.